# Property 'routerDelegate' threw exception; BackToBackPatternClassifier

Tags: spring-batch, filewriter

I am trying to use `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`, that time i am getting the below error.

> Property 'routerDelegate' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than one non-void public method
>   detected with single argument

My Classifier is:

```
public class ItemNameNodeClassifier implements Classifier<Master, String> {

    @Override
    public String classify(Master classifiable) {    
        return classifiable.getName();
    }    
}
```

the configuration is:

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="classifier" ref="nameIndicatorClassifier" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="nameIndicatorClassifier" class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
        <property name="routerDelegate">
            <bean class="com.batch.ItemNameNodeClassifier"/>
        </property>
        <property name="matcherMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="S" value-ref="itemWriter1" />
                <entry key="N" value-ref="itemWriter2" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Any help on this appreciated.

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: There is an opened ticket about this issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2030)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used @Classifier annotation instead of Classifier interface and it was working.

```
public class ItemNameNodeClassifier {

    @Classifier
    public String classify(Master classifiable) {

        return classifiable.getName();
    }

}
```